# Consecutive number generator program on each execution

Tags: java

I would like to write a program that generates the consecutive number starting from 1 every time it is *executed*.

It will print 1 at the first execution, then it will print 2 at the next execution, and so on.

What is the shortest way to do this in Java?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You have to save **number** into file on exit and read number from  the file on start.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of doing this is to save the number somewhere and look it up.

For instance, you start the first time, look for a given file. If it's not there, create it, write 1 to it, output 1, exit.

Second time, file is there, read the content (it's 1), increment that value, write 2 to the file, output 2...

So on and so forth.

Have you tried writing the code? You can easily search for how to open a file, write, read, etc, there are plenty of questions regarding these problems.

Comment: Well, thank you very much for your response. However, that was not what I was looking for. I had that in mind but I asked if there was a better or shorter way to do it (especially without files) but it seems that this site is not the place to ask for help since the question is already downvoted and I was blamed for making you people do my homework. But thank you anyway friend.

Comment: People here expect you to explain what exactly you're having problems with. An advice for your next questions is to explain what have you tried and if you're having troubles getting something to work, and be specific about your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting, platform-independent option would be to employ the [Java Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/preferences.html).